# Creating a post project function for a freelancer websites using wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, web, plugins

I'm creating a Freelancer website using WordPress. For that, I need to create a posting project function for the employers. I have tried many plugins up to now to create this functionality. This function will let the employer post their project/job using a form (a file uploader should also be included) after submitting the posted project/job should be visible on the projects/jobs page of the site. Can someone give me a solution for this on how should I create this and if there are any good plugin in WordPress that I can use to create this? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/.

You can try it. Maybe it'll helpfully for you.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no file uploader in that plugin